# React Jest Test Fails when setState Called in Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to mock out the a service that returns promises so that I can verify it gets called with the correct parameters.  The way the service is called varies based on the `state` and the first call to the service sets the `state`.

When setting the state in the promise it is not updating unless I wrap the assertion in `setTimeout` or completely stub out the promise.  Is there a way to do this with just a plain promise and an expect?

My component:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {results: []};
    this.service = props.service;
    this.load = this.load.bind(this);
  }

  load() {
    if (this.state.results.length === 0) {
      this.service.load('state is empty')
                  .then(result => this.setState({results: result.data}));
    } else {
      this.service.load('state is nonempty')
                  .then(result => this.setState({results: result.data}));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button id="submit" onClick={this.load}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My test:

```
it('Calls service differently based on results', () => {

  const mockLoad = jest.fn((text) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve({data: [1, 2]});
    });
  });

  const serviceStub = {load: mockLoad};

  let component = mount(<App service={serviceStub}/>);
  let button = component.find("#submit");

  button.simulate('click');

  expect(mockLoad).toBeCalledWith('state is empty');

  button.simulate('click');

  //this assertion fails as the state has not updated and is still 'state is empty'
  expect(mockLoad).toBeCalledWith('state is nonempty');
});
```

As mentioned, the following works, but I'd rather not wrap the expect if there's a way around it:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    expect(mockLoad).toBeCalledWith('state is nonempty');
    done();
  }, 50);
```

I can also change how I mock the function to stub out the promise which will work:

```
const mockLoad = jest.fn((text) => {
  return {
    then: function (callback) {
      return callback({
        data : [1, 2]
      })
    }
  }
});
```

But I'd like to just return a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Sinon with Sinon Stub Promise I was able to get this to work.  The stub promise library removes the async aspects of the promise, which means that `state` gets updated in time for the render:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonStubPromise = require('sinon-stub-promise');
sinonStubPromise(sinon);

it('Calls service differently based on results', () => {

    const mockLoad = jest.fn((text) => {
        return sinon.stub().returnsPromise().resolves({data: [1, 2]})();
    });

    const serviceStub = {load: mockLoad};

    let component = mount(<App service={serviceStub}/>);
    let button = component.find("#submit");

    button.simulate('click');

    expect(mockLoad).toBeCalledWith('state is empty');

    button.simulate('click');

    expect(mockLoad).toBeCalledWith('state is nonempty');
});
```

See:

http://sinonjs.org/

https://github.com/substantial/sinon-stub-promise

Answer (score 2):

React batches `setState` calls for performance reasons, so at this point

```
expect(mockLoad).toBeCalledWith('state is nonempty');
```

the condition

```
if (this.state.results.length === 0) {
```

is most likely still `true`, because `data` has not **yet** been added to `state`.

---

Your best bets here are

- Either use [forceUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate) between the first and second `click event`.
- Or split the test into two separate, while extracting common logic outside of the test. Even the `it` clause will become more descriptive, for instance: `it('calls service correctly when state is empty')` for the first test, and similar for the second one.

I'd favour the second approach.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later.

Read more [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: Thanks! I tried both the suggestions but unfortunately neither of them worked, the problem seems to be with waiting for the promise to finish rather than the batching of `setState` as if I remove the promise and just call setState outside of a `.then` the test works fine.

Comment: I see, it is then very unfortunate if the promise resolution is delayed until everything else is done...  in this case I don't see an obvious clear solution either. Please post your solution if you find something elegant, thanks!